# How to disable SELinux on Ubuntu with Ansible?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible, selinux

The playbook:

```
---
- name: Update repositories cache
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install build-essential
  apt: name=build-essential state=present

- name: Disable SELinux
  selinux: state=disabled
```

The result:

```
TASK [common : Update repositories cache] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [server]

TASK [common : Install build-essential] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server]

TASK [common : Disable SELinux] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "libselinux-python required for this module"}
```

I tried to find `libselinux-python` but it seems like not exist. When I try some other libraries such as `python-selinux`, can't been installed on the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change you tasks to this. You need to install `python-selinux` first. **[`Ansible intro install requirements`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)**

You should add this to your tasks.

```
- name: Install the libselinux-python package
  apt: name=python-selinux state=present
```

Whole tasks will be like this.

```
---
- name: Update repositories cache
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install build-essential
  apt: name=build-essential state=present

- name: Install the libselinux-python package
  apt: name=python-selinux state=present

- name: Disable SELinux
  selinux: state=disabled
```

Comment: I tried that, but it said: `fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No package matching 'libselinux-python' is available"}`.

Comment: @cloud_cloud Hope this will be helpful take a look https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty-updates/libselinux

Comment: Thank you very much. But this time: `fatal: [rancherserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.33.111 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_T58IMt/ansible_module
_selinux.py\", line 226, in <module>`.

Comment: @cloud_cloud I think that is something which is not related to your current post. Issue which you have mentioned above has been fixed now.

Comment: Maybe,I think so, too. By the way, which release version I am using is `bento/ubuntu-16.04`. An vagrant official hub version.